# WPF UserControl creating in code, Bindings not registering with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have created a Generic WPF Control, so the layout is all defined in code. This is all fine and I have added bindings which work first time round, for example:

```
private bool btEnabled { get { return SOME_LOGIC; } }

Button bt = new Button { Content = "Button" };
bt.SetBinding(Button.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding { Source = btEnabled, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

Whenever something happens which affects btEnabled property I am calling INotifyPropertyChanged but the PropertyChanged event is always null, I can't work out why the binding isn't registering the PropertyChanged event.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `btEnabled` is a property, that too private!

So presumably there are two mistakes...

Your `Binding` should set `Path="btEnabled"` not `Source=btEnabled`
And your btEnabled property should be public.

Comment: Further there needs to be some source, so most likely `Source` should be set to `this`.

Comment: @H.B, shouldnt an unset Source indicate default DataContext? Do we need to set it explicitly even in code behind?

Comment: The OP originally set the Source to the property, so presumably that property is on the same object, thus he/she rather likely did not intend to bind to the DataContext but the current object, i.e. `this`. If of course the DataContext is already set to `this` then that will not be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've tried public but no luck there, I'll leave it as public for now though.

A quick note, the binding does actually work when first run, the Property is called when the binding is set and the SOME_LOGIC is calculated, just not subsequently.

Changing the Binding to Path results in the error "{"Object 'System.Boolean' cannot be used as an accessor parameter for a PropertyPath. An accessor parameter must be DependencyProperty, PropertyInfo, or PropertyDescriptor."}"

Comment: @Mim, my bad ... try `Path = new PropertyPath("btEnabled")`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried to get the error shown in my last comment though!

Comment: Are you sure you used `"btEnabled"` (a string with double quotes) and NOT simply `btEnabled` (bool)?

Comment: Sorry, yes the error was for btEnabled, "btEnabled" does work when Source is set to this, thanks a lot!